# Why is full space not used to show pages in Google sheet

Tags: user-behavior, accessibility, experience

I was using google sheets and saw this ( Please refer image).
Space was limited to a certain number of sheets though there was space left towards the end.

Is there any logic for this ??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to note that the limitation is the total tabs length, not their amount.

The logic behind this solution seem to be related to a panel that shows from the right, that used for components configuration or other purposes, that left side of it will match the tabs limit when the panel shown.

On the screenshot you've provided, there is a button at the right bottom corner, if it's clicked it will open the panel I'm referring to.

Here is an example how it looks when a panel is opened:

[image]